# What is the comment syntax in Yesod (hamlet) templates?

Tags: templates, haskell, yesod, hamlet, shakespeare-text

I just can not find how to comment line in hamlet template. Is there some syntax for comments? Like

```
-- <p>Some code should be ignored by template
```

or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the latest version the line comment starts with `$#`, also ordinary html comment delimited by `<!--` and `-->` is available. Check it in the [source file](https://github.com/yesodweb/shakespeare/blob/cddb06487220c0fae5fa9176d244391f45226f0b/Text/Hamlet/Parse.hs#L157).